# При подключении к БД пустая строка соединения

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Пытаюсь загрузить свой небольшой сайтик на хостинг, вроде все нормально, но проблема с подключений к БД. Строка соединения почему-то пустая.

```
public class ProceduresDB
{
    private string connectionString;
    public ProceduresDB()
    {
        connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Vocabular"].ConnectionString;
    }
    public void InsertHG(Details dls, string table)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert" + table, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Word", SqlDbType.NChar, int.MaxValue));
        cmd.Parameters["@Word"].Value = dls.Word;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Value", SqlDbType.NChar, int.MaxValue));
        cmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = dls.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 1));
        cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (SqlException err)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(err.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Класс с процедурой для работы с базой и файл веб конфиг.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Vocabular" connectionString="workstation id=Vocabulary.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=Air_SQLLogin_1;pwd=**********;data source=Vocabulary.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=Vocabulary "
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Логин и пароль точно те?

Comment: Логин и пароль те

Comment: Собственно у меня строка "connectionString" пустая, и я не могу понять почему.

Comment: @Baka Выкачайте реальный конфиг с сервера, и проверьте что там есть connection string. может быть он затерся при деплое.

Comment: И  в правду, спасибо за помощь. Тему можно закрывать.

Comment: @Baka если проблема неактуальна - удалите вопрос

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.